# why do the context value assigned to default value?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-component

why do the context value assigned to default value despite of using value prop in provider??
here is when I created the context:

```
export let exchangeContext=React.createContext();
```

I created provider in the same component

```
 <exchangeContext.Provider value={"aya"}>  </exchangeContext.Provider>
```

and when I console log the value in the consumer i get undefined as the default value

```
 <exchangeContext.Consumer>
       {(value)=>{
         console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write consumer if you used context (writing consumer is the old way before useContext hook was a thing)

In your consumer file do this

```
import { exchangeContext } from './App' // wherever the main context is
```

then in your function body

```
const value = React.useContext(exchangeContext)
```

then in your return body

```
return <>{value}</>
```

see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext for more info

Comment: I cannot use hook because I use class component

Comment: do you know why the value prop is not working?

Comment: Did you import exchangeContext? A lot of your code is missing.

Comment: yes I have imported it
`import {exchangeContext}from"./nav";
 `